# Adding checkout link to success message list

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, messages

I would like to add checkout link to `<li class="success-msg">`. I have problem with adding below code to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php`. How could it be done?

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl(); ?>">Checkout</a>
```

Comment: you want to add link for particular message or all success messages?

Comment: I would like to show the checkout link in success message after "...has been added to your shopping cart."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit success message of add to cart you have to override `CartController` and change success message of `addAction`You can  simple add `<a>` tag in success message eg. -

```
$value = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
$message = $this->__('Product added to cart. <a href="%s">Click here to checkout.</a>', $value);
```

path to cart controller - `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`

Comment: May you provide me the path to cartController

Comment: I have added link in the answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion in line 262 (in addAction fuction) but it did not show any link to checkout in success message Neither in category list nor in product page. Consider that based on our setting after adding product to cart customer stays in current page and will not be directed to cart page.

Comment: if your changes are not applied please check if any module is overriding your CartController.php